# popup with 2 html files how to get popup close event?

Tags: javascript, html

I open the popup like this:

```
function showWindow(url){
    var newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=300,width=350');
        newwindow.onbeforeunload =  function () {
            alert("closed");
        };
}
```

HTML

```
<button type="button" onclick="return showWindow('popup.html')">bbb</button>
<p id="text" style="display:none">aaa</p>
```

and in popup.html :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
</head>

<body>
a: <input type="text" id="name"/> </br>
a: <input type="text" id="surname"/></br>
a: <input type="text" id="cardNumber"/></br>
a: <input type="text" id="way"/></br>
a: <input type="text" id="freePlaces"/></br>

<button type="button" onclick="window.close()">G</button>
</body>
</html>
```

but when I close that popup using window.close my onbeforeunload is not being called.
How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't setup `onbeforeunload` in your function opening the window, but on the new window (`popup.html`), like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    alert("closed");
};
```

To be able to close the new window however, setup a function on the opener page like this:

```
function closeWindow() {
    newwindow.close();
}
```

Then call it in your new window like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.opener.closeWindow();">G</button>
```

Make sure the `newwindow` has the same name as what you've given to your variable opening the window (`var newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=300,width=350');`).

#### EDITED!

I have an even better one for you...

#### Original page:

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" onclick="toggleMe('popup.html',false);">bbb</button>
```

**JS**

```
function toggleMe(url, closeMe){
    var newwindow = window.open(url,'name','height=300,width=350');
    if (closeMe) {
        newwindow.close();
    }
}
```

#### popup.html:

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.opener.toggleMe('popup.html',true);">G</button>
<!-- Make sure popup.html is the same as above -->
```

**JS**

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "closed"; };
// Hint: I used return "text" because alert doesn't seem to work on Chrome
```

Comment: Ok, made some edits, sorry about that... it should be good now!

Comment: I can not call the method from opener. it sets exception

Comment: what do you mean "it sets exception"?

Comment: Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Comment: is your `popup.html` an external URL or a page on the same domain as from where you're calling it? because this error might be caused by the fact that you have the original and the new window on different (sub)domains... [have a read at this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Comment: I made another edit, making the script a little easier, though again, if you're calling `popup.html` from a different domain, this may not help...